# Change Color of TextInputLayout when Focused

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have been looking how to change the color that the focused TextInputLayout picks, the colorAccent because I need to do it programmatically.

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/atom_edittext_til"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/atom_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/greyGhost"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

I have that define in my XML
[image]
I need to be able to change the green cursor and the underline programmatically because the colors comes from the server. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

I already try,
setBoxStrokeColorStateList, boxStrokeColor, backgroundTintList, if a try to do background.setTint I get a Null Reference
From the resource file is not an option
Also tried creating an extension

```
fun TextInputLayout.setDefaultStrokeColor(
    color: Int
) {
    try {
        val defaultStrokeColor = TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("defaultStrokeColor")
        defaultStrokeColor.isAccessible = true
        defaultStrokeColor.set(this, color)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        // failed to change the color
    }
}
```

does not work